# White plot and initial and boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-conditions

I am solving numerically the following hydrodynamics equations:

```
eq1 = D[\[Rho][t, x, y], t] + D[vx[t, x, y] \[Rho][t, x, y], x] + 
   D[vy[t, x, y] \[Rho][t, x, y], y];
eq2 = D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vx[t, x, y], t] + 
   D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vx[t, x, y]^2, x] + 
   D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vx[t, x, y] vy[t, x, y], y];
eq3 = D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vy[t, x, y], t] + 
   D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vy[t, x, y]^2, y] + 
   D[\[Rho][t, x, y] vx[t, x, y] vy[t, x, y], x];
eq4 = D[1/2 \[Rho][t, x, y] (vx[t, x, y]^2 + vy[t, x, y]^2) + 
     3/2 p[t, x, y], t] + 
   D[1/2 \[Rho][t, x, y] (vx[t, x, y]^2 + vy[t, x, y])^2 vx[t, x, 
       y] + 5/2 p[t, x, y] vx[t, x, y], x] + 
   D[1/2 \[Rho][t, x, y] (vx[t, x, y]^2 + vy[t, x, y])^2 vy[t, x, 
       y] + 5/2 p[t, x, y] vy[t, x, y], x];
```

with boundary and initial conditions:

```
bcs = {\[Rho][t, 10, y] == 10^-23, \[Rho][t, -10, y] == 
    10^-23, \[Rho][t, x, 10] == 10^-23, \[Rho][t, x, -10] == 10^-23, 
   vx[t, 10, y] == 0, vx[t, -10, y] == 0, vx[t, x, 10] == 0, 
   vx[t, x, -10] == 0, vy[t, 10, y] == 0, vy[t, -10, y] == 0, 
   vy[t, x, 10] == 0, vy[t, x, -10] == 0, p[t, -10, y] == 0, 
   p[t, x, 10] == 0, p[t, x, -10] == 0};
ic = {\[Rho][0, x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {10^-23, x^2 + y^2 >= 1}}], 
   vx[0, x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{10, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {0, x^2 + y^2 >= 1}}], 
   vy[0, x, y] == 
    Piecewise[{{10, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}, {0, x^2 + y^2 >= 1}}], 
   p[0, x, y] == 0};
```

I solve it with `NDSolveValue`:

```
{dens, Vx, Vy, P} = 
 NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, eq4 == 0, bcs, 
   ic}, {\[Rho], vx, vy, p}, {t, 0, 100}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]
```

The above code works, however there are a series of problems:

1. If I write `DensityPlot[dens[0.1, x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]`, I get:

[image]

What is the white area in the middle of the plot? It is always there, no matter which time I set.

2. Even if the code works it doesn't do what I expect: the area in the middle should expand in the rest of the plot, but instead it just grows. I suspect the problem are BC/IC: how do I set these conditions in such a way that the central region expands?
3. It also seems that my conditions are not used correctly: the density at the initial time is:

[image]

There are negative regions which should not be there

I also tried using FEM, but the equations are not linear and version 11.3 cannot handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the default [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html).

Using your definitions:

```
{zmin, zmax} = #[{dens[0.1, x, y], -10 < x < 10, -10 < y < 10}, {x, 
     y}] & /@ {NMinValue, NMaxValue}

(* {-0.156896, 1.} *)

Manipulate[
 DensityPlot[dens[0.1, x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 75,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic,
  PlotRange -> pltRng],
 {{pltRng, All, "PlotRange"}, {Automatic, All, Full, {zmin, zmax}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob, can you please clarify where does the definition of `pltRange` come from? Why is manipulate used here? Thanks!

Comment: @CATrevillian - The `Manipulate` is used to simplify demonstration of the effect of using the different values for the `PlotRange` option. `pltRng` is the control variable for the `Manipulate`. Since the control variable is restricted to one of four values (`{Automatic, All, Full, {zmin, zmax}}` the `ControlType` defaults to `SetterBar`. The control variable passes the selection to the plot through the option `PlotRange -> pltRng`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what aboutp poblem 3? Why do those regions with negative density appear in the initial conditions?

Comment: I answered the part concerning the white area of the plot. I don't know anything about the BC/IC.