# How to export to an .eps file?

Tags: export

This is a followup question to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250588/8822).

The code works great but I now want to export the resulting `DensityPlot`. I have tried clicking the plus on the right of the image and selecting `paste snapshot` and then to export it to an .eps using `Export["~/Desktop/img.eps",%]`. This created an image on my desktop but it was 97 Mb.

Is there a more simple way to export this plot and also to have a smaller file?

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but this sounds like it could be solved by the `rasterizeBackground` function from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71870/rasterized-density-plot-with-vector-axes)

Comment: Why not define your fig:  `myFig = DensityPlot[..]` then `Export[~/Desktop/img.eps, myFig, "EPS"]`?  Try that.  If it is too large, try `.../img.png, myFig, "PNG"]`